# Is there a "data type" to that can store both Combobox items and ListBox items?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.0

What I am trying to do is pass a list of items to a method rather than the item itself.

Comment: what is your platform? asp.net? silverlight? wpf? (etc.)

Comment: What type of item are you dealing with here?  Is it a class?  A struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, everything can be boxed to 'Object' and they may share a hierarchical parent closer (I don't have the docs in front of me, and I don't think it's important enough to this discussion to check).

I'm wondering exactly what you're attempting to accomplish.  If you have a `ComboBox` and a `ListBox` which both contain the same kind of objects (let's just call them strings, for now, but it should apply to anything you want, I'd think), you can, with relative ease, extract the object from the `ListBoxItem` or from the`ComboBoxItem` and then pass around `List<string>` or `IEnumberable<string>` or whatever.

If they are not the same object type, for whatever reason, you may need to check what you're doing and why- the likelihood of needing to combine a two lists of two completely different objects and pass the resultant concatenated list around is fairly slim.

Answer (score 0):

If your list box items are of type `Car` a collection of them can always be cast to `IEnumerable<Car>`. If you take in an `IEnumerable<Car>` to as parameter to the method you can loop through the items with `foreach` or apply linq methods to it. If you want to be able to modify the collection's content you will have to be a bit more specific and e.g. use an `IList<Car>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListItemCollection YourList = YourDropDownList.Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `System.Windows.Controls` a `ComboBoxItem` is a `ListBoxItem`.

Of course, everything is an object.